# MVC Core: What is meaning of DbContextOptions<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

What is the definition of `DbContextOptions<T>`? I did not understand this, [MSDN DbContextOptions<TContext>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptions-1)

> The options to be used by a `DbContext`. You normally override `OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder)` or use a `DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>` to create instances of this class and it is not designed to be directly constructed in your application code.

Are we saying, that `TContext` can be used to create multiple connection strings for different databases?

Comment: Hi Bricelam, if you want to put your comments into answer, I can give points thumbs up if you want, thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance could even be using a different provider (e.b. SQLite and SQL Server)